# attach magicsuggest on dynamic elements

Tags: jquery, dynamic, magicsuggest

I would like to ask how can I attach magicsuggest on multiple dynamic elements?
Has anyone have done it before?

Heres the situation, everytime i type "comma" or hit "enter" it should create a panel with 2 inputs with magicsuggest each. So if i input:

```
 1 towel, 2 plates
```

it should create 2 panels with 2 inputs each with magicsuggest.

The above situation is already done, but now the problem is that when it loads all the inputs with magicsuggest it always focuses on the first input. i can select on the others but always focus on the first.

I have tried this code, but to no avail.

```
var ms = {};
for(var i = 1; i <= 2; i++){        

    ms[i] = $('#text_area_request_'+i).magicSuggest({
        id: "request_id_" + i,
        name: "request_id[" + i + "]",
        allowFreeEntries: false,            
        width: 350,
        maxSelection: 1,    
        data: ["Wifi", "Steak", "Food", "Water"],           
    });

}
```

Thanks

Answer (score 0):

First of all you have forgotten a comma in the end of the data key ("Water"],).

If you remove it and still does not work.. you can try the following..

Create a function attachMagicSuggest('text_area_request_0') which will take as parameter the ID of the input you want to populate with the data.

Every time you create a new panel (or whatever you call them) run this function as well.

```
function attachMagicSuggest(inputId){

    var ms1 = $('#'+inputId).magicSuggest({
     placeholder: 'Select a cuisine',
     allowFreeEntries: false,            
     width: 350,
     maxSelection: 1,    
     data: ["Wifi", "Steak", "Food", "Water"]
    });

}
```

Answer (score 0):

I'm not entirely sure what you mean by focus, but perhaps the issue is that you are referencing the same object each time. Make sure you are working with a different object each time through the loop. The return value of magicSuggest can't be appended directly to another jquery object, so I had to use a function similar to this:

```
function buildMagicSuggest(id, options, setValue) {
    var $input = $('<input>', {id: id, class: 'form-control'});
    var data = [];
    for (var i = 0; i < options.length; i++) {
        if (options[i] === null) {
            continue;
        }
        var name = options[i] === '' ? '&nbsp;' : options[i];
        data.push({id: options[i], name: name});
    }
    var magic = $input.magicSuggest({
        placeholder: '',
        allowFreeEntries: true,
        selectPositions: 'bottom',
        selectionStacked: false,
        maxDropHeight: 145,
        maxSelection: 1
    });
    magic.setData(data);
    setValue && magic.setValue([setValue]);
    return magic.container;
}
```

Then you can use this function like this:

```
$('#the-form').append(buildMagicSuggest(
    inputId,
    ["Wifi", "Steak", "Food", "Water"],
    "Wifi"
));
```

The key was finding the correct property of the magicSuggest object which contained the entire control (container).